# public variable in php class not working

Tags: php, pdo

I have php class like

```
class muhasebe {
    public $smh_id;             
    public function smh_kayitekle($data){
        global $conn;

        $stok_miktar_hareket="INSERT INTO `smh`( `urun`, `iscilik`, `birim`, `adet`, `miktar`) 
                                                VALUES 
                                                ('$urun',
                                                '$iscilik',
                                                '$birim',
                                                '$adet',
                                                '$miktar')";                                                                
        $conn ->exec($stok_miktar_hareket);
        *****$this ->smh_id***** = $conn->lastInsertId();
    }
}
```

when run code, part  between **** not working. 
$conn is a pdo variable  my aim is to use smh_id in another function in the class. when I use `$this->smh_id`  without `$this` prefix (`$smh_id`), it is okey 
but then I can not use in other function.

Comment: Have you called the function ``smh_kayitekle`` before trying to get ``$this->smh_id``'s value?

Comment: I am  not trying to  get  $this->smh_id , just I am setting for later use

Comment: Is the other function in the same class? Are you calling the method on the same `muhasebe` object?

Comment: Where are the variables `$urun`, `$iscilik`, etc. defined?

Comment: @Tapos Oops, I accidentally did that when I was fixing his formatting.

Comment: You should be using prepared statements for query security/stability.  Many developers will urge you not to use `global`, and advise that you should pass the connection in as a parameter (a few ways to do this).  You are performing no basic error checking techniques, so debugging your code will always seem like a chore and/or a guessing game (for you or anyone else).  Please read about `try {} catch {}` blocks for pdo.  There are several places where your snippet could be failing; for this reason I am voting to close as Off-topic: Why isn't my code working.

Answer (score -1):

If `smh_id` is a variable you have to write

`$this->$smh_id = //code here`